Which one to choose as the uncertainty?
Consider ten measurements of a value in an experiment. I know that I should take the mean to estimate the "true" value. But I am confused on how to determine the uncertainty, do I use standard deviation of these measurements as the uncertainty, or should I use the standard error, that is
$$\sigma / \sqrt{10}$$
Where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of these measurements. Which one to use?

The uncertainty should be reported as the standard deviation of the measured values. The uncertainty is reflected in the spread of values obtained in the measurement process. You would want to use the standard error if you were, for example, only considering the mean of say 4 of the total of ten measurements, i.e. standard error refers to a sample mean and not the population mean. Since your sample space consists of 10 measurements, and you are concerned with all ten, then you are interested in the population mean and standard deviation as opposed to the sample mean and standard error.

The standard deviation of your measurements will be the same as long as your measurement technique does not change. But the standard error on the mean, $\sigma/\sqrt N$, reflects the fact that repeated measurements give you a better estimate of the mean as your dataset grows.
Suppose you are measuring the average value of a fair six-sided die. Your measurements are drawn from a uniform distribution with mean 3.5 and standard deviation $\sqrt{35/12}=1.7$. Perhaps your first four rolls are all ones and twos. This gives you a poor estimate of the mean — but if the die is fair, future rolls will bring your estimate of the mean closer to the true value in a $1/\sqrt N$ sort of way.

"The standard deviation of your measurements will be the same..." This is only true if you are measuring one single thing multiple times, e.g. the speed of light. However, if you are given a sack of 10 oak leaves to measure, the standard deviation of a sub population of 5 leaves can differ from that of 8 leaves.

Perhaps I should have written "the standard deviation of the distribution from which your measurements are drawn," or suchlike. Like the standard error on the mean, there is an estimator for the standard error on the standard deviation.
